# Does Amazon SNS support direct mobile to mobile push?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, but the way Amazon SNS is described it sounds like a cloud-to-device push, of the sort that might be used for advertisements and other notifications.

I'm wondering if it easily supports mobile-to-mobile pushes, such as sending a data packet from one Android phone to another (specific) Android phone.  Or, from an Android phone to an iOS device?

The data packet I'm describing might contain text & floating point data, or an SQL structure, or a bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Amazon SNS will not do mobile-to-mobile push.

Reply from Amazon:

To answer your question, no AWS SNS will not send a direct push message from one mobile device to another. SNS uses Amazon's servers as the publisher which will send the messages to the subscriber end points. You can view more of this here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMobilePush.html

You would need to use the application on the mobile device to handle the messages from one device to another using the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)

Answer link:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=144057